# Moving a Few Observations to New Rows in R?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, spread

I am trying to create a few new columns, based on specific observations in an existing row in my data frame. Below, I have a few rows as a representative example:

```
test.df <- tibble(can=c("can1","can2","unmarked","invalid","blank"),
             votes=c(177000,441000,11000,1300,20000))
```

Here, I want to maintain the `can` column, but put **both** the `unmarked` and `invalid` columns on the right, as their own new columns. Is there a way to spread portions of a column, based on an observation type, such as `unmarked` or `invalid`?

I have tried using `spread(can,votes)`, but this obviously makes a column for both candidates, which is not ideal.

Any help is appreciated here. Thank you!

Comment: can you show the expected output

Comment: I am looking for a table with the following columns: can, votes, unmarked, invalid, with their respective values in the test tibble above.

Comment: thanks, if you  can show the values in the expected otuput, it would help in crossmatching.

Comment: Of course. I an aiming for the following: can=c(can1,can2,blank), votes=c(177000,441000,20000), unmarked=c(11000,NA,NA), invalid=c(1300,NA,NA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get you most of the way there. Without knowing your use case, I don't know exactly what you want to do with unmarked or invalid. I am assuming your data is much bigger. This will get you just the can and votes, but as pivot_longer will match the value in the row for unmarked and invalid it fills.

```
library(tidyverse)
test.df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "can",
              values_from = "votes") %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("can1", "can2", "blank"),
               names_to = "can",
               values_to = "votes")
```

Comment: Yes, this is excellent! Thank you! Swear my weak spot is spreads and pivots.

Comment: Happy to help!! Here is a nice vignette on the pivots https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html